# YouTube API changes

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Mysteriously. The past days the functionality of my application has been declining.
First I started getting errors when modifying playlists. Now the JavaScript API got bricked.

It's my homebrewed YouTube player: [You-Fi](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bxsg2VAdqvTKNGs2NVhCaUk4dFU/youfi.html) (I've been at the web console for the past hours)

([You might want to see the function I use to get the player from their servers](https://googledrive.com/host/0Bxsg2VAdqvTKNGs2NVhCaUk4dFU/youtubeHandle.js).)

As of a few hours ago it stopped working completely. It seems Google is doing changes or the browser security on cross page interchange has been tightened. And I can't seem to find ANY news on this.

It seems that the player object instance that the new `YT.Player()` constructor supplies, has completely changed. It's like it's been minified or something. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) doesn't seem to have noticed the changes...

I'm completely at a loss here. What's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a mistake from [YouTube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube). Some information is in *[Issue 4706: iframe API: onStateChange not firing](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4706)*.

Comment: I don't even know if this is it. But it fits! THNX!!!"The engineering team has identified an issue" YEAAAAA! "Get that engineer out of here!!"